# Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null [All my code runs and my non of my elements return null]

Tags: javascript, html

I have this weird problem where, I get this error... but I have gone through every other way to prevent my `document.getElementById('.....')`; from returning null... and I even added an if statement, where if they are null, the code wouldn't even run... but yet I get and error... but the weird thing is that the code still runs!

Below I have pasted an image of the `Error on console` and also the html and javascript files of the page... I didn't include the css codes as I don't think they are important to know what is actually going wrong... but If you require it for some reason, I will post that too, later on.

Now to give you guys an idea of what happens and what the codes do, Basically, its a signup log in system, where the form (either login or signup) is inside the `div` called `content-dynamic`. That is because, I coded it to load the contents using AJAX in pure javascript, based on when the `btn-change` is clicked. On loading the site for the first time, we get no errors in the console, then when the `btn-change` is clicked, it replaces the contents of the login form to the sign up form (The text contents of the `btn-change` change as well).

Now if the user now wants to go back to the earlier page / form, he clicks on the `btn-change` button again and that now loads in the login form (which was there in the first place) and it is here that the error occurs.

Note that during this change of forms, this error occurs only once (Which means that if I were to clean the console after this error pops up, no matter how many times I press the `btn-change` button, the error never pops up again). This error however doesn't interfere with the page loading or any other functionality of my page. But what I really want to know is why is this error happening in the first place?

I tried using an event listener to check if the content is loaded and if it is loaded, only then to execute the javascript codes, but this doesn't seem to fix it. As I have already said and as you can also see in the code, I have also put an if statement, where if anyone of the `getElementById()` returns null, the code won't even work. And I am now out of ideas. Would be very grateful if someone can help me. Also please (if possible) present the suggestions in pure javascript and not jQuery. Thank You in advance!

[Error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF19I.png)

```css
(function() {
    const btnChange = document.getElementById('btn-change');
    const containerDynamic = document.getElementById('container-dynamic');
    
    let toggle = true;
    
    btnChange.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(toggle) {
            if(btnChange) {
                btnChange.style.backgroundColor = "#22a7f0";
                btnChange.style.color = "#fff";
                btnChange.textContent = "Login";
                getSign();
                toggle = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(btnChange) {
                btnChange.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                btnChange.style.color = "#22a7f0";
                btnChange.textContent = "Sign Up";
                getLog();
                toggle = true;
            }
        }
    });
    
    function getSign() {
        if(containerDynamic) {
            let xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr1.readyState == 4 && xhr1.status == 200) {
                    containerDynamic.innerHTML = xhr1.response;
                }
            };
            xhr1.open('get','site/signup.php',true);
            xhr1.send();
        }
    };
    
    function getLog() {
        if(containerDynamic) {
            let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200) {
                    containerDynamic.innerHTML = xhr2.response;
                }
            };
            xhr2.open('get','site/mheader.php',true);
            xhr2.send();
        }
    };
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <title>Something</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/mstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="logo-hiw">
                <img id="logo" src="resources/css/img/logo.png">
                <img id="hiw-symbol" src="resources/css/img/help.svg">
            </div>
            <div id="container-dynamic">
                <?php
                    require "site/mheader.php";
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="or">
                <p>OR</p>
                <div class="link">
                    <button id="btn-change" class="button">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/mscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is clearly happening inside some Chrome extension; look at the stack trace you posted.

Comment: Did you even care to look at where that error was coming from? It clearly isn't from your code, but from an extension you have.

Comment: Yes I did, I just didn't know what to do about it... Would be glad if you could let me know if there is something I can do about it.

Comment: Use incognito mode